# Swampdragon: how to determine a channel the message was published to?

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, swampdragon

In my project backend sends a lot of messages published to different channels.
I can see from browser console the message arrived has `channel` property.
But the problem is a callback passed to `swampdragon.onChannelMessage` doesn't get that channel information. It gets strange channels list instead.
So when a message arrives (in browser) I can't figure out the channel it was published to and therefore handle it properly.

I found the code where that channel info is stripped off https://github.com/jonashagstedt/swampdragon/blob/master/swampdragon/static/swampdragon/js/dist/swampdragon.js#L261

```
if ('channel' in e.data) {
  var channel = swampDragon.channels[e.data.channel];
  delete(e.data['channel']);
  swampDragon.settings.onchannelmessage(channel, e.data);
  return;
}
```

So my question is how frontend developer can figure out what channel the message arrived was published to in order to be able to handle the message properly?

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but in case you weren't able to solve this:

```
swampdragon.open(function() {
  swampdragon.subscribe('notification', 'notification', null, function (context, data) {
    // Successfully subscribed to the notification channel
  }, function () {
    console.error('Error', arguments);
  });
});

swampdragon.onChannelMessage(function(channels, message) {
  if (channels.indexOf('notification') > -1) {
    // Message sent on the notification channel
  }
});
```

In `onChannelMessage` the `channels` argument is an array of channels the incoming messages was sent to. You can use `indexOf` to check the channel you are interested in exists in the list.